# sed'ing out HTML section

Tags: sed

I do have long HTML table output which consists of dozens of records. Example looks like this:

```
<tr onclick="window.location='/team/90687/';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="">
  <td class="number">163124</td>
  <td class="img">3</td>
  <td class="user">
    <span class="name">Mosse John</span>
  </td>
  <td class="number">3332</td>
  <td class="number">497</td>
  <td class="number">20</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="window.location='/team/342465/';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="">
  <td class="number">163124</td>
  <td class="img">2</td>
  <td class="user">
    <span class="name">Sus Peter</span>
  </td>
  <td class="number">3332</td>
  <td class="number">450</td>
  <td class="number">20</td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to extract section which contains user belonging to 90687, so I type:

```
sed my_html_file -e '/window.location.*90687/,/window.location/ !d'
```

Unfortunately it also fetches first line of next session which I would like to avoid. I did go trough 101 sed and awk tricks, but only solution I found is

```
sed my_html_file -e '/window.location.*90687/,+9 !d'
```

which would mean that I am interested in fetching 9 lines after pattern. The problem is that I cannot rely on "9" or any other number. Is there any way to solve it by sed ?
BTW I am strongly interested in sed.

Comment: Too bad you're married to sed for this: HTML parsing should be done with an HTML parser.

Comment: @glennjackman While I agree you in general, my side note: sed actually can embed regexps and sub-regexps, making it more close to a context-insensitive interpreter. Problem is that it is complicated and everybody is using it as a regular language translator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not sure if the closing `</tr>` might be inlined with the following record, you can try this

```
sed -n -E '/window\.location.*90687/,/<\/tr>/ {
/<\/tr>/! { p }
/<\/tr>/ { s/(.*)<\/tr>.*$/\1<\/tr>/ p } }
' input.txt
```

Though there are probably more elegant solutions, this will handle also things like this:

```
<tr onclick="window.location='/team/90687/';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="">
  <td class="number">163124</td>
  <td class="img">3</td>
  <td class="user">
    <span class="name">Mosse John</span>
  </td>
  <td class="number">3332</td>
  <td class="number">497</td>

  <!-- Confusing Row -->
  <td class="number">20</td></tr> <tr onclick="window.location='/team/342465/';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="">

  <td class="number">163124</td>
  <td class="img">2</td>
  <td class="user">
    <span class="name">Sus Peter</span>
  </td>
  <td class="number">3332</td>
  <td class="number">450</td>
  <td class="number">20</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi there<br\> 
your solution is very good,  I just want ask 1 more question:
in your 3rd line you  didnt put semicolon before p (print) - why ?
at the same time sed return syntax error if s and p in 3rd line would be in reversed orded. Why  s followed by p doesnt require semicolon?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for your data:

```
sed my_html_file -e '/window.location.*90687/,/<\/tr>/ !d'
```

This will print all the lines until the closing tag `</tr>` is met.

More complex solution:

```
sed my_html_file -n -e '/window.location.*90687/,/window.location/ { H;x; /window.location.*window.location/ !{ x;p }} '
```

This will print all the lines until second `window.location` is met.